# SUM,COUNT with UNION in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the following schema:

```
DATA | CAUSE_1 | TIME_1 | CAUSE_2 | TIME_2 | CAUSE_3 | TIME_3
```

The `CAUSE.*` field (`VarChar`) can not contain any string, and if so, the field `TIME.*` is 0.

I'm trying to create a query, but unfortunately without success, where I would have the result display in this form:

```
CAUSE | TOT_TIME | N_RIPET_CAUSE,
```

where:

- In `CAUSE` I have a list of what is contained in `CAUSE_1 ... CAUSE_3`,
- In `TOT_TIME` the sum of the values in `TIME_1 ... TIME_3`,
- In `N_RIPET_CAUSE` the number of repetitions of each `CAUSE`.

I hope I explained.

Comment: This is a SQL anti-pattern; multiple columns should have their own table.

Comment: where is TEMPO_1 in your table?

Comment: I'm not seeing any `ACTION` column in your schema also.

Comment: can you make sample data of your table ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not change the schema. Is there a way to run the query in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT DATA ,CAUSE , TOT_TIME , N_RIPET_CAUSE
 FROM ( select DATA, CONCAT(`CAUSE_1`,' ',`CAUSE_2`, ' ', `CAUSE_3`) as CAUSE ,
 sum(`TIME_1` + `TIME_2` +`TIME_3`) as TOT_TIME ,
 (count(`CAUSE_1`)+count(`CAUSE_2`)+count(`CAUSE_3`)) as N_RIPET_CAUSE
 FROM your_table
 group by DATA
 ) t
```

[**SEE SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7679/6)

EDIT.

try this

```
     ( select DATA , `CAUSE_1` as CAUSE ,
     sum(`TIME_1` + `TIME_2` +`TIME_3`) as TOT_TIME ,
     (count(`CAUSE_1`)+count(`CAUSE_2`)+count(`CAUSE_3`)) as N_RIPET_CAUSE
     FROM Table1 
    group by DATA)
  union all
    (select DATA , `CAUSE_2` as CAUSE ,
    sum(`TIME_1` + `TIME_2` +`TIME_3`) as TOT_TIME ,
    (count(`CAUSE_1`)+count(`CAUSE_2`)+count(`CAUSE_3`)) as N_RIPET_CAUSE
    FROM Table1
    group by DATA   )
  union all

    (select DATA , `CAUSE_3` as CAUSE ,
    sum(`TIME_1` + `TIME_2` +`TIME_3`) as TOT_TIME ,
    (count(`CAUSE_1`)+count(`CAUSE_2`)+count(`CAUSE_3`)) as N_RIPET_CAUSE
    FROM Table1
    group by DATA   )
```

[**SQL DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7679/11)

**EDIT:**

try this due to your need

```
 select cause, sum(time) Tot_time, count(cause) N_Ripet_Cause
 from(
    select  cause_1 as cause, time_1 as time
    from Table1
    union all
    select  cause_2 as cause, time_2 as time
   from Table1
   union all
   select  cause_3 as cause, time_3 as time
   from Table1
 ) t
 group by cause
```

[**DEMO SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94442/10)

Comment: Yes, it is close to what I want to do. The only thing is that in the field CAUSE I would not get the display of the data in this way
"element1 - element2",
but:
element1
element2

Comment: updated my answer , like that you mean ? its element1 element2 element3

Comment: Forgive my English, thatu?

Comment: Yes, yes, not horizontally but the vertical

Comment: Yes, but I did not understand why each item present in CAUSES, the column N_RIPET_CAUSE always returns the value 3. Should count how many times a string CAUSES is present.
If the string "try" there is only one times, N_RIPET_CAUSE should bring one, is not it?

Comment: can u give your sample data , or edit my sqkfiddle and put your data and tell what u wish to ouput. it was just my sample data

Comment: CREATE TABLE Table1
 (`CAUSE_1` varchar(3), `TIME_1` int, `CAUSE_2` varchar(3), `TIME_2` int, `CAUSE_3` varchar(3), `TIME_3` int)
;
 
INSERT INTO Table1
 (`CAUSE_1`, `TIME_1`, `CAUSE_2`, `TIME_2`, `CAUSE_3`, `TIME_3`)
VALUES
 ('try', 12, 'try', 13, 'edi', 14),
 ('XXX', 11, 'XXX', 13, 'XXX', 16)
;with this schema I expect to find:
TRY | 25 | 2
EDI | 14 | 1
XXX | 40 | 3 [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94442/1)

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness ... that's what I tried to do these days ... thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change the table structure, then in order to get this result, you are going to need to *unpivot* the columns into rows.

MySQL does not have an unpivot function but this can be done using a `UNION ALL` query. You can then apply the aggregate to those values to get the final result:

```
select cause, sum(time) Tot_time, count(cause) N_Ripet_Cause
from
(
  select data, cause_1 as cause, time_1 as time
  from yourtable
  union all
  select data, cause_2 as cause, time_2 as time
  from yourtable
  union all
  select data, cause_3 as cause, time_3 as time
  from yourtable
) src
group by cause
```

Comment: you are missing 'as':

select cause, sum(time) as Tot_time, count(cause) as N_Ripet_Cause

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I edited and corrected my post for mistakes I made.

Comment: @bluefeet: Sorry, my bad: just checked it, `as` is really not required.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a select from union select like that:

```
select * from
(
    select cause_1 as cause, time_1 as time from tableName
    union
    select cause_2 as cause, time_2 as time from tableName
    union
    select cause_3 as cause, time_3 as time from tableName
) as joinedValues
```

Then you could perform any actions from that select.
Like number of each clause:

```
select cause, count(cause) from
(
...
) as joinedValues
group by cause
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack is on the mark - you've got too many possibly redundant cells in your table structure. Use relations to eliminate such occurrences.

***DataTable***
dID | Data

***instancesTable***
ID | dID | CAUSE | TIME

Then use NATURAL JOIN upon the two tables to extract the information;

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable NATURAL JOIN instancesTable WHERE dID=? LIMIT 3
```

This query will return a list of causes and times of whatever occurred on the ID of the 'Data' in the first table.

Edit: *N_RIPET_CAUSE* can be found using a **SUM(CAUSE)** on the dID.